# KeyError trying to create a new column that sums other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I must add a new column, which includes the sum of three existing columns.

This is my df: https://i.stack.imgur.com/88vbj.png = data2

I tried with:

```
data2['AdminHours'] = data2.apply(lambda row: row['AdminHrs1'] + row['AdminHrs2'], axis=1)
```

or with

```
data2['C'] = data2['AdminHrs1'] + data2['AdminHrs2']
```

but I got the following message:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._maybe_get_bool_indexer()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._unpack_bool_indexer()

KeyError: 'AdminHrs1'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:
-> 2900                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2901 
   2902         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'AdminHrs1'
```

Also I tried with:

```
data2['AdminHours'] =  data2[['AdminHrs1', 'AdminHrs2']].sum(axis=1)
```

but got the following message:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-58a368bd1a0d> in <module>()
      1 
      2 
----> 3 data2['AdminHours'] =  data2[['AdminHrs1', 'AdminHrs2']].sum(axis=1)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis, raise_missing)
   1296             if missing == len(indexer):
   1297                 axis_name = self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)
-> 1298                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   1299 
   1300             # We (temporarily) allow for some missing keys with .loc, except in

KeyError: "None of [Index(['AdminHrs1', 'AdminHrs2'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Please help :(

Comment: What is the output from `data2.columns`? It's possible that there's trailing whitespace like `'AdminHrs1      '`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including example input and your code (i.e. how `data2` is defined). There's probably whitespace in the column label. You can [edit]. For more tips, see [ask].